# X-rays are absorbed by bone. If the width of the bone increased in proportion to the wavelength, would bone absorb radio waves?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, radiation, x-rays, radio-frequency

What I’m interested in here, are the properties of different electromagnetic waves, and the factors that cause them to be absorbed by different materials and be influenced in other ways by different materials.

Comment: It does somehow mix size and composition....

Answer (score 1):

Macro width is not a factor when you want to examine absorption/transmission of EM wave. Its microstructure is what determines it. For example, regardless of how large a glass is, it probably transmits above 80% of visible light. It's because of SiO2 crystal structure it has, not the size.
However if you are just interested in blocking radio waves, radio waves don't usually transmit, they merely reflect back and fourth and diffract obstacles. That's why we put antenna outside of car, building, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> X-rays are absorbed by bone. If the width of the bone increased in proportion to the wavelength, would bone absorb radio waves?

If a bone increased in width in proportion to the difference in size between X-rays, and radio waves, it would be very, very thick indeed. The longest X-rays are considered to be around 10 nm. The shortest radio waves might be considered to be around 1 mm. Between them you have a factor of about 100,000 if I have done my math correctly.

Although radio waves are not absorbed particularly well by relatively non-conductive materials, such as wood and cement (and I would presume bones), given that the bones would be mountainous, yes, I would imagine that they would absorb radio waves, or at least *block* them. You may get more reflection than absorption.

Longer wave radio waves can propagate through the earth, (and I would presume bones). But longer wave radio waves would correspond to even that much more "bone mass". If we increased the radio wavelength from 1mm to, say, 100m, that would be another factor of 100,000. So, now instead of being mountainous, the bones would be planetary sized. So, even with longer wavelengths, I think the bones would block radio waves.